# Why does Exit Animation not work upon exiting an activity by tapping on back arrow which is on top-left of Toolbar/AppBar?

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I'm developing a **material design** app & I've declared an **Exit Animation** in `MainActivity`.

When I'm exiting by clicking back button, the animation is working, but upon exiting the app by tapping on **back arrow** which is on top left of Toolbar/AppBar, the animation is not working.

Here's `MainActivity.java` file's code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    int normalTabTextColor = Color.parseColor("#64B5F6");
    int selectedTabTextColor = Color.parseColor("#2196F3");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // Call some material design APIs here
            // enable transitions
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        } else {
            // Implement this feature without material design
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(normalTabTextColor, selectedTabTextColor);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_profile:
                // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
                    // Call some material design APIs here
                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(profileIntent,
                            ActivityOptions
                                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
                } else {
                    // Implement this feature without material design
                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(profileIntent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_support_development:
                // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
                    // Call some material design APIs here
                    Intent supportDevelopmentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SupportDevelopmentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(supportDevelopmentIntent,
                            ActivityOptions
                                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
                } else {
                    // Implement this feature without material design
                    Intent supportDevelopmentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SupportDevelopmentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(supportDevelopmentIntent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
                    // Call some material design APIs here
                    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(settingsIntent,
                            ActivityOptions
                                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
                } else {
                    // Implement this feature without material design
                    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(settingsIntent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_help:
                // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
                    // Call some material design APIs here
                    Intent helpIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(helpIntent,
                            ActivityOptions
                                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
                } else {
                    // Implement this feature without material design
                    Intent helpIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(helpIntent);
                }
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Accept a Request";
                case 1:
                    return "Post a Request";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't know what is wrong here.

Please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the case for 'home' in `onOptionsItemSelected` function.

Add an entry in switch like below:

```
    switch(id){
            .....
            case android.R.id.home: 
            supportFinishAfterTransition();
            return true;
            .....
    }
```

Basically when you click the button on top, **menuitem's** id is **android.R.id.home**
and hence the exit animation should be handled here as well. See if it helps.

Comment: First check if you are able to trace that event inside that code. If yes then apply your animation. Check the I'd of the button you are pressing. It is usually Android.R.id.home or R.id.home. First check the event.

Comment: hey, I'm just a beginner, I can't understand what you are saying!
Please explain in easy language!

Comment: @HammadNasir Ok. No problem. See the button which you are clicking at top must have an id right ?? You can get the idea by printing it using System.out.println() inside onOptionsItemSelected. When you click the back button onOptionsItemSelected function is called. Inside that function
you have already handled some cases like R.id.action_profile, R.id.action_settingsR.id.action_support_development, R.id.action_settings and R.id.action_help. Now to handle the back button you will have to add an entry for that as well inside onOptionsItemSelected function. Press the button and print the id.

Comment: Use that id and add an entry inside switch cases. Whenever you will press the back button on top onOptionsItemSelected will be called and it will look for the case when id = your home button's id. So just add your exit animation code inside that case and it will start working. Any doubts ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92013/discussion-between-hammad-nasir-and-sahu).

Comment: Inside case android.R.id.home: 
                 this.finish(); 
                // your animation code 
                return true;
Don't forget to accept answer :)

Comment: Are you calling finish method ? Is that method getting executed. Please check it first.

Comment: And yes use overridePendingTransition for doing animation. And please post your updated code.

Comment: And yes use overridePendingTransition for doing animation. And please post your updated code. Which version you are on ? If you are below lollipop then you can't use  ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation. use overridePendingTransition for below lollipop.

Comment: I'm checking the android version & declaring animations only for android 5.0 & above.

Comment: Yes so if you are below 5.0 you have no animation code. Handle for cases where you are below 5.0 using overridePendingTransition.

Comment: Add supportFinishAfterTransition();
            return true; in your case android.R.id.home. See this article https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition It should work now.